# Why would one use the equation environment instead of the align environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I have noticed that the environment `align` appears to do everything that the environment `equation` accomplishes, plus the additional features of aligning equations and arranging them in an organized manner on the page.

I have started writing up some lecture notes and have noticed that I use `align` so often that I now use it in place of `equation`!

Are there any reasons why I should not do this? ie; why I would want to use the `equation` environment when I don't need all the features of `align`? or is it acceptable to use `align` throughout my document?

Comment: in short `equation` has some space saving features that `align` does not. Thus if you know what to look for you'll often be able to see when an author has been using `align` for one-liners.

Comment: you shouldn't use align if there is only one equation, and more generally you shouldn't use it if there are no alignment points (necessarily the case if there is only one equation)

Comment: Personaly, I use equation with one equation, align (align*) with several equations with an alignment position and gather (gather*) with sveral equations, formulas to be centered. Allowdisplaybreak takes care of page skips efficiently.

Comment: @pzorba75 I'm not aware of the gather environment. How does this differ from align?

Comment: see `texdoc amsmath` gather is for multiple equations with no alignment, also multline which is for a single but multi-line equation with no alignment